# RoR 2.3.8: Vendored Paperclip is throwing: Factory is not a class (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, paperclip

The error:

```
vendor/plugins/paperclip/shoulda_macros/paperclip.rb:113: Factory is not a class (TypeError)
```

which points to the line `Class Factory` I may not know much about RoR, but I'm pretty sure this error is silly (Saying factory isn't a class, when it's being defined right here (though I suppose extended if it already exists"

```
class Factory
  include Paperclip::Shoulda  #:nodoc:
end
```

This error occurs when I run: `bundle exec rake test:units`

Answer (score 1):

The error likely means that something else has already defined `Factory` as a module. Without a list of your other gems and/or code, it's hard to guess what that might be.

Comment: as it turns out, I just removed paperclip as a vendored gem, and just included it in my gemfile... .all is well now.